# What is the rationale for the order of folders in bin\x64\Debug\net5.0-windows7.0\win-x64

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-5

Is there any rationale for why Visual Studio orders the folders in a VS c# project in the following way?

```
bin\x64\Debug\net5.0-windows7.0\win-x64\myapp.dll
```

I could be wrong, but if it were me, I would order them this way to group things more rationally, proceeding from the lowest level hardware (x64) to the next level (runtime) to the next level (framework) then debug/release versions of myapp.dll (the highest abstraction level).

```
x64/win-x64/net5.0/debug/myapp.dll

x64 - the hardware layer
win-x64 - the runtime hardware abstraction layer
net5.0-windows7.0 - the software framework that supports the apps and libraries
Debug - the debug/release versions of my app library
myapp.dll - my app
```

With the VS folder ordering, all the Release versions of everything (all runtimes, frameworks, and apps) are grouped under the x64/Release folder. So if I wanted to add or remove a runtime, I would have to visit all the folders (N folders) for all the permutations of Debug/Release x Nframeworks.

In contrast, if I wanted to remove a runtime in my example structure, I would only have to visit one folder to remove everything that used the runtime to be deleted.

Is there a rationale for the current VS ordering? I feel like I might be missing something important or obvious. Thank you.

Comment: The `software framework` is `net5.0-windows7.0`, not `net5.0`. `net5.0-windows7.0` provides OS-specific interfaces that can't be used in cross-platform .NET projects. `win-x64` isn't a hardware abstraction layer, it's a target runtime. If you worked on a Mac, you'd have an `osx-x64` folder. If you developed on Mac but published for Windows, you'd have both folders side by side

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was just trying to save typing a few characters. I updated the question. You also point out an instance of my question. The runtime lives between the hardware and the framework I think, providing some very low-level APIs. (For example, C projects have very small runtimes because C is so close to the hardware.)

Comment: It's not a matter of typing, it's a different meaning. If I worked on a Mac to build a web app to run on Windows (as I did for the last 2 years), I'd very much prefer the current hierarchy, with the two different runtimes as the leaf folders. Otherwise I'd have two completely different, deep hierarchies to navigate

Comment: Thank you for your perspective; I do not have the MacOS cross-platform NET perspective you have. I'm thinking that I would rather have my Debug/Release folders as the leaves deep in the runtime tree, whereas you prefer the runtimes as leaves deep in the Debug or Release tree. At least we both like the idea of the framework moniker in the middle.

Comment: Debug and Release can be common for all SDKs, platforms and bitness. .NET dlls can target AnyCPU.  That's why they're on top, and the platform folder is a subfolder. That's how things are since 2001, which means reversing the hierarchy would break just about every tool. Before Windows Vista, very few people targeted 64-bit

Comment: If someone wanted to target .NET 5 on Windows, and create either a 32-bit or 64-bit binary (perhaps because they need to bundle native binaries for SQLite), the inverted hierarchy would result in two deep folders for the same OS, same runtime

Comment: Finally, the runtime can be a specific OS version, eg `win10-x64` or `win7-x64`. If that were above the SDK, it would also result in different deep hierarchies to hold binaries for the same SDK. When you build a WinForms app in .NET 6 though, you probably want to have one SDK folder, with the specific runtimes underneath.

Comment: Thank you again for the added details and rationale. As it happens, your last case (WinForms on NET 5/6) is exactly my scenario. I think you made a good rationale point by saying that AnyCPU enables Debug/Release to be on top. I'm always using x64 because of other libraries, so I wondered about Debug/Release on top too. Surely your explanations will help someone else some day. Thank you.

Comment: There is not.  The solution platform for .NET should be AnyCPU.  Adding the x64 platform is possible, but doesn't make much sense.  It gets locked-in when you publish, not when you build.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your input as an expert. Are you saying there is not rationale? I used to build everything with AnyCPU, but I constantly got MSIL warnings from mismatches (even though the code itself always ran fine). I got tired of the warnings so switched to building everything x64 from the start. I've also read elsewhere on SO that committing to x64/x86 is a good thing because AnyCPU is "meaningless." I can't remember if did that switch before or after moving to NET 5.

Comment: It is a chronic misunderstanding in .net.  The name of the solution platform plays no role whatsoever.  All that matters are the settings in Project > Properties > Build tab.  The platform and 32-bit preferred settings there determine what the jitter does at runtime.   For .NETCore projects you want platform = AnyCPU and 32-bit preferred off, the former ensures you'll never see the warning.  And it now builds to bin\Debug and publishes to bin\Debug\net5.0-windows7.0\win-x64

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the VS recommendations. Since I build my 50+ solutions in parallel using MSBuild command lines, what do you recommend that I use for arguments on the command line? (I plan on doing experiments to see how the PropertyGroup properties in the csproj file interact with the presence or absence of MSBuild CLI args at build time. If you have advice about what properties to set in the csproj file for MSBuild operations, I would love to read them here.) Thank you again. You are a tireless helper of the uninformed like me... :-)

Comment: It occurs to me that I need to work out answers for three things: (1) What to use in the VS Build dialog (AnyCPU, 32bit off, you say). (2) What to manually put into the csproj PropertyGroup section (Platforms=x86;x64? TargetFramework=net5.0-windows7.0?, RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64?, SelfContained=false? and of course UseWindowsForms=true for solutions that need it). and (3) what CLI args to use (are all platform, TFM, RID, and self-contained required/best practice on the command line for build and publish (which invokes build too)? I want to build the whole set in 32 or 64 bit mode. Thank you.